# Sequential Transactions in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a Spring Boot application with a REST endpoint that inserts `Order`s in a MSSQL database. The data is validated upon insert, i.e. there is a `maxAmount` threshold that is computed across all orders in the database and may not be exceeded. If `maxAmount` is exceeded a Exception should be thrown.

The current logic uses a simple `@Transactional` on the Service method that inserts the orders. The requests to the REST endpoint can come in short sequence. The default MSSQL isolation level is `READ_COMMITED` which means that the query in the current transaction cannot read data modified by another transaction that has not yet committed. Therefore I sometimes get `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException`s. Using `@Transactional(isolation=READ_UNCOMMITTED)` would solve the CannotAcquireLockException but has the risk of dirty reads.

How can I process the insertion of `Order`s sequentially? The REST-Endpoints would have to "wait" somehow in that scenario which would also be a performance hit on the caller side.

Comment: Explain a bit more on why and how you are getting CannotAcquireLockExceptions? That seems like it should occur under deadlock situations, and if so, you'd have to analyze what the processes are doing in the transactions and order them a bit more appropriately and consistently so that the 'second' process doesn't obtain locks the first might need. Any process getting such an exception just needs to reevaluate/reprocess the transaction. The other alternative is sequentially handling everything with either locking in the database, or putting it in a single messaging queue.

Comment: My domain model is a little bit more complex that outlined here. The `Order` entity has a One-to-Many relationship to another entity that has a version field (annotated with `@Version`) and that is updated within the transaction. Thats the cause for the `CannotAcquireLockExceptions`.